# Spring MVC controller not invoked

Tags: java, spring, servlets, model-view-controller, controller

The project structure is as you can see in the picture below:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCuBs.png)

The web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mvc</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
      org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/webapp.WEB-INF/mvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

The mvc-servlet context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="main.java.controller"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/webapp.WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The controller:

```
package main.java.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomePageController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/home", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(){
        return "homepage";
    }

}
```

The jsp called "home" is just some random html.

However, when I try to access the url

> http://localhost:8080/CatalogFacultate/mvc/home

I get the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tHna.png)

I used the debugger and the method from the controller is not even invoked. So there is a problem with the spring configuration. I've searched on the internet a lot and I'm out of ideas. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try access the hello servlet with this url http://localhost:8080/mvc/home. Am sure it will help

Comment: The war file is called "CatalogFacultate". In the webapps folder inside Tomcat, I also have the ROOT webapp. So the the URL that I have used is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Change /mvc to /mvc/* in the url pattern of org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet in your web.xml file
That will make all uri with pattern /mvc/* to be routed to spring dispatcher and later to your servlet

Comment: Tried it, no result.